# Error occurs when I try to read a Double value from a NSDictionary object

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nsdictionary

```
let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves, error: nil) as NSDictionary
let dataDict = (jsonDict["data"] as NSDictionary).copy() as NSDictionary

NSLog("%@", dataDict)

let hp = dataDict["hp"] as Double
let pay = dataDict["pay"] as Double
```

NSLog's output is exactly the content of dataDict, but when it comes to `let hp = dataDict["hp"] as Double`, Xcode is always stuck here:

```
0x1083da9c2:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax) // Thread 6: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

How could I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Environments: Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317), iOS 8.0 Simulator

`dataDict` is like this:

```
{
    hp = 20090458525;
    pay = 63887638528;
}
```

---

Solved by the following code:

```
var hp: Double
if let str = dataDict["hp"] as AnyObject! as String! {
    hp = NSString(string: str).doubleValue
}
```